# Conserved azimuthal generalized momentum = conserved $z$-component of angular moment?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, momentum, coordinate-systems

The Lagrangian for a spherical pendulum of length $l$ is

$$
L = (1/2) m l^2 (\dot{\theta}^2 + sin^2(\theta) \dot{\phi}^2) + mg l cos \theta
$$

Landau and Lifshitz state,

> "The coordinate $\phi$ is cyclic, and hence the generalized momentum $p_\phi$, **which is the same as the z-component of angular momentum,** is conserved."

I am struggling to see how the polar coordinate system generalized momentum is the same as the z-component of the Cartesian coordinate system angular momentum.

I imagine a simple spherical polar coordinate drawing will help
[image]

Can anyone point out where I'm missing something that makes this clear?

Comment: We can't point out where you are missing anything because you haven't outlined anything that you are thinking. All you have said is that you can't figure it out.

Comment: Conceptually, if it satisfies you, you can think that translation in $\phi$ in polar is equivalent to rotating along $\hat{z}$ in cartesian. Hence, if the conserved quantity is unique, both should give the same conserved quantity. Hence $$M_z = p_{\phi}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very hard, so I won't complete all the steps.

Using the definition of the generalised momentum $p_\phi$, you should be able to show that

$$p_\phi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}} = m l^2 \sin^2{\theta}\dot{\phi}.$$

Similarly, using the definition of the angular momentum (see the end of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), if this isn't obvious):

$$\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r \times p} = m l^2 (\dot{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{\phi}} - \dot{\phi} \sin{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{\theta}}) $$

Let's calculate the $z-$component of $\mathbf{L}$. Converting the above equation to Cartesian coordinates (while keeping in mind that the unit vectors *must* be written in terms of $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$), you can easily show that

$$L_z = m l^2 \sin^2{\theta}\, \dot{\phi}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! The main point I realized while working through your solution was that spherical coordinates are orthogonal! $\hat{r} \times \hat{\theta} = \hat{\phi}$... + cyclic permutations. That plus your note that I need to express the spherical unit vectors back into Cartesian yielded the result!  :D Thank you :) Minus sign on the second term in your second equation I believe :)

Answer (score 2):

The "sphere position" vector is:

$$\vec{R}=l\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \varphi  \right) \sin \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \\\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \\ \cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

you obtain the velocity

$$\vec{v}=\vec{\dot{R}}=l\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \sin \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \dot\varphi +\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \dot\vartheta \\ \cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) \sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \dot\varphi +\sin \left( 
\varphi  \right) \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \dot\vartheta 
\\ -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \dot\vartheta 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

and the z-component of the angular momentum is: $$\vec{L}_z=\left(\vec{R}\times\,m\vec{v}\right)_z=
m\,\left(R_{{x}}v_{{y}}-R_{{y}}v_{{x}}\right)=m\,l^2\,\sin^2(\vartheta)\dot{\varphi}$$